# OmniSharp autocomplete for class names, not just methods/properties?

Tags: c#, vim, unity-game-engine, mono, omnisharp

I'm a bit new to C# and trying to get Unity/Mono working with Vim.  I get OmniSharp autocomplete for methods/properties, but would like the autocomplete to pop up for class names.

For example, if I am in the middle of typing the following, I do not get a suggested autocomplete:

`new Vect`

Now if I hit `<C-x><C-o>`, I do get the correct OmniSharp autocomplete suggestions for this class.

Is there any way for OmniSharp to suggest classes rather than only methods and properties?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want the autocomplete to happen when you don't have the '.' in the front and assume you are using YouCompleteMe plugin

Add this line to your .vimrc:

`let g:ycm_semantic_triggers = {'cs' : ['.','re![_a-zA-z0-9]']}`